# Autochange implicit variable declaration to explicit

Tags: c#

I'm going to convert my C# code to Java but converter tool doesn't understand `var`. So, before conversion, I need to change this

```
var array = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

to this

```
string[] array = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

automatically for all my code. How I can do that?

Comment: You can do it manually by the time you get the answer :)

Comment: Isn't that what the converter is supposed to do? have you tried a different converter?

Comment: **CTRL** **+** **H**?

Comment: You don't understand `var` but you know what to do? However, it's not a programming question. Voting to close...

Comment: You can try reflector & disassemble the built assembly.

Comment: To all, how can he use Find & Replace the var keyword if he doesn't know the Type to replace with ahead of time.

Comment: Not to state the obvious- but you're probably going to have to make more changes to your code than just `var`s to switch from C# to Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatically? you can use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) in order to achieve it.

While the caret positioned on the `var` keyword, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will give you:

[image: Specify type explicitly]

And if you want to automate and apply this modification over all of your source-code files, use the *Clean-Up* feature:

Resharper **->** Tools **->** Cleanup Code **->**  Create a new profile/modify an existing one and then navigate to C#->Use 'var' in declaration. Set the "Replace direction" to "Can (change) 'var' to type usage" and "Local variable declaration style" to "Always use explicit type".

Comment: But how to do this for all files and lines in one click? I can't do Alt+Enter on every line, so much time.

Comment: @bobby I'll update my answer.